# Figma font issue. Figma doesn't recognize one of my local fonts

Tags: fonts, figma

No matter what i do, Figma won't pick up my local font. Although, it picks up all my other fonts...

My Qanelas font is definitely installed on my Ubuntu system. I've tried restarting the computer etc...

[image]